# How to do batchUpdate in yii2

Tags: yii2, query-builder, batch-updates

Only batchInsert is available in yii2, `bacthUpdate` is not available in yii2, how can we do this in yii2 like Codeigniter `batchUpdate`?

Comment: As far as I remember there is no method generating `UPDATE` query exactly like described in CodeIgniter docs [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) (`$this->db->update_batch()`).

Answer (score 5):

Use updateAll() on your model.

```
Customer::updateAll(['status' => 1], 'status = 2');
```

From Yii 2 [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#updateAll()-detail)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Please try this

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->update(self::tableName(), 
            [ 'field1'=>$value1 ], //columns and values
            [ 'field2'=>$value2, 'field3'=>$value3 ]) //condition, similar to where()
            ->execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some facts.

At first [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/Command.php) there is no batchUpdates, but batchInsert is exist.

At second, one man from Yii core said on [russian forum](https://translate.google.ru/translate?hl=ru&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Frmcreative.ru%2Fblog%2Fpost%2Fyii2-batch%23c9264) that there is no batchUpdate in Yii2 Query builder cause it is too specific to implement it for various DB-systems.

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update  `batchUpdate` is there in `Codeigniter`, please see the above link. I too can't find the `batchUpdate` in Yii2. Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 1):

We can do it in the same way as batchInsert only replacing it with update I leave an example:

```
//table columns
$colums = ['reportCode','idActivity','requirement','direction','area'];

//where $_POST['data'] are data to be actulate received from the view
$arrayInserts2 = array();
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $value) {
    $arrayInserts2[] =  [ 'reportCode'=>$code,
                          'idActivity'=> $key,
                          'requirement' => $value,
                          'direction' => $_POST['direction'][$key],
                          'area' => ''
                        ];
}

//runs the update of multiple records
$updateRecord = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('table_name', $colums, $arrayInserts2)->execute();
```

in this way we update several records in a single operation.

Answer (score -1):

foreach ($arr_data as $data) {
$update_membership[] = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
->update(`table_name`, [
`field_name` => value,
], [
`id` => $data[`id`],
])->execute();
}

Comment: This is not the same as a batchUpdate. This would execute a command for every row being updated.